# JS getElement by ID+Class

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-selectors

```html
<div id="myId" class="sampleClass">
  Div with id and class
</div>
<div class="sampleClass">
  Div with only class
</div>
```

I want to get div with id as well as class. Is there any other better way to do other than below:

```js
var sample = document.getElementsByClassName("sampleClass");
for(var x = 0; x<sample.length; x++) {
  if(sample[x].id=="myId")
    return sample[x];
}
```

Comment: Yup $("#myId.sampleClass"). I want it with JS

Comment: [`document.querySelector('#myId.sampleClass')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: `document.getElementById` and nothing else. All ids must be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sample = document.querySelectorAll("#myId.sampleClass");
console.log(sample[0]);
```

Output:

```
<div id="myId" class="sampleClass">
```

Browser support:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Answer (score 1):

For getting multple `IDs`:

```
<div id="myId" class="sampleClass">
  Div with id and class
</div>
<div id="hisId" class="sampleClass">
  Div with id and class
</div>
<div id="herId" class="sampleClass">
  Div with id and class
</div>
<div class="sampleClass">
  Div with only class
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var sample = document.getElementsByClassName("sampleClass");
for(var x = 0; x<sample.length; x++) {
    var getId = sample[x].getAttribute("id");
    if(getId){
        console.log(getId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery as well :
HTML:

```
<div id="myId" class="sampleClass">
  Div with id and class
</div>
<div class="sampleClass">
  Div with only class
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var sample = $('.sampleClass'); //getting object by class
   for(var x = 0; x<sample.length; x++) {
    if(sample.attr('id')=="myId") //checks ID attribute 
    console.log(sample);    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's incorrect usage of `id` attribute.
`id` must to be unique  on the page!
So, if you need element with `id`, you use just:

```
document.getElementById(id);
```

This method is incredible fast - browser has a map of `<id, HTMLElement>`

Also you can use `jQuery` wrapper with `#id` selector, but it more universal and as result is much slower.

```
$('#'+id); // jQuery
document.querySelector('#'+id); // Native
```